# How to add a scrollbar into a chat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I made myself a chat on the Laravel framework. Everything works fine, but you need to make a scrollbar for chat. How can i do this?

My code that calls the chat is:

```
 <!-- Chat -->

 <div id="chatContainer" style="">
     <div id="chatHeader">Chat</div>

     <div id="chatBody" style="display: none;">
         <div id="chatScroll" class="nano has-scrollbar">

             <div id="chat_messages" style="right: -17px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;" class="nano-content" tabindex="0" style="right: -17px;">
                 <div id="messages">
                 </div></div>
             <div class="nano-pane" style="display: none;">
                 <div class="nano-slider" style="height: 406px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"></div></div></div>
         @if(!Auth::guest())
             <textarea id="sendie" maxlength="255" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
         @else
         @endif
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Chat END -->
```

In ChatController i use by default 30 last messages. But i can't make scrollbar. How i can add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to:

```
<div id="chatContainer" style="">
     <div id="chatHeader">Chat</div>

     <div id="chatBody" style="display: none;">
         <div id="chatScroll" class="nano has-scrollbar" style="overflow-y: scroll;">

             <div id="chat_messages" style="right: -17px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;" class="nano-content" tabindex="0" style="right: -17px;">
                 <div id="messages">
                 </div></div>
             <div class="nano-pane" style="display: none;">
                 <div class="nano-slider" style="height: 406px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"></div></div></div>
         @if(!Auth::guest())
             <textarea id="sendie" maxlength="255" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
         @else
         @endif
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Chat END -->
```

basic add a `style="overflow-y: scroll;"` to the div you wish to scroll